# odoo How to implement a tab in product category

Tags: python, xml, tabs, odoo

I created a new fields in product category, but this file does'nt have tab (notebook).
Do you have  an idea to do that ?

I try to insert the tabs like this :

Information -- General

Currently the tabs are like this

tab 1 : General

tab 2 : Information

Thank you.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="product_category_form_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.category.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">product.category</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_category_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="name" position="after">
                    <field name="categories_image" colspan="4" row="2" widget="image" class="oe_avatar oe_left"/>
                    <notebook position="after">
                        <page string="Information" position="after" name="parent_id">
                            <group col="4" colspan="4" string="General">
                            </group>
                        </page>
                        <page string="Option">
                            <group col="4" colspan="4" string="General">
                                <field name="categories_id" readonly="1" />
                                <field name="categories_name"  placeholder="Categories Name"/>
                                <field name="categories_description" placeholder="Categories Description"/>
                            </group>
                            <separator string="SEO" colspan="4" />
                            <group col="4" colspan="4">
                                <field name="categories_seo_title"  placeholder="SEO Title"/>
                                <field name="categories_seo_description" placeholder="SEO Description"/>
                                <field name="categories_seo_keyword" placeholder="SEO keywords"/>
                            </group>
                         </page>
                    </notebook>
                </field>  
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Not getting your problem, what is the problem if the file is not having a 'notebook' element in it? Can you please brief more about the problem.

Comment: I have edited the document below with code with  <notebook>, Yesterday Itry does'nt work, I do an error. I inserted a little more information, I think it's better to understand.

Comment: I found a solution it's almost perfect but not again. It's ok for me. The code has been adapted

Comment: hello @Kurama it'll be great if you post your solution as an answer so it can benefit other members of the community. don't you think so?